# "Intercept" flash socket with java

Tags: java, flash, sockets

given a flash application that opens a socket connection to a webserver, is it possible to reads packets exchanged  with a java application, without redirect all the flash traffic ( that is, without programming a socket proxy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do requires lower level network analysis than sockets. Namely libpcap and its Java bindings , [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/). This will let you capture packets much in the same way wireshark does, but from Java. The other options are analysing Wireshark logs after an experiment and that can get clunky quite quickly. You may also consider writing a custom [wireshark dissector](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html#id4904553).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think is to modify the `hosts` file to list your Java server address as if it was the destination address.

BTW if your are only interested in examine the network traffic for that app, you could also use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: This is like setting up a proxy... I'd like much more "see" the packets without redirecting everything. Something like what whireshark does, but restricted to a specific socket instead of logging all the network traffic.

Comment: Wireshark can log only specific traffic if you specify a filter.

Comment: ok, with wireshark you can do what i need to do. Now, since I must analyze those packets, can i do the same with a java app?

Comment: Well, not exactly. If your flash app doesn't have a proxy setting you can't specify it ( and that's what I thought your problem was )  About doing that with Java, is possible and no at the same time. Because that's all  low level OS access, so,  if you get the native library to do that, then you could invoke it from Java and do what you need.