# C# How would I intercept all packets and find out the IPs through hooking?

Tags: c#, hook, pinvoke, ip-address, intptr

Actually I have three questions:

1- According to [Nazar Grynko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281720/3312744) answer, Is it only intercepting the three functions(send , recv,and connect) will help me to anticipate all the packet in my machine?

2- If I hooked the three functions, How to get an IntPtr which points to a sockaddr structure from a P/Invoked native function?

3- Send, and recv are not having sockaddr, so how to figure out the addresses?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Monitoring all traffic on the machine is harder than hooking three functions from user mode code. This is going to need to be done in kernel mode. That means a driver. Not something for C#.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , what about the Easyhook and deviare they are for C#. Another thing, is it better to shift to capturing packet tools like SharpPcap. or stick with the hooking.

Comment: I thought you said you want to detect all packets on the machine. You aren't going to do that from a desktop app running in the context of a user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm new to these stuffs so could you explain it more, and what should I do. My aim is to monitor the network  traffic for all processes in my machine(outgoing or incoming). I started with Pcap(sharppcap) but it captures the packets with out knowing the process receiving or sending it, I tried to retrieve the port # from the headers and excute _netstate_ but still not all the packets can be associated to a process . So, I shifted to hooking, by hooking all the system calls that results a network packet(s) I thought its possible to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

1. The functions you described are a part of the `POSIX` standard. This means that when you use these functions on Windows, you're actually calling a wrapper that eventually translates to a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). You can send packets without the use of this function (e.g, by using the Windows API).
2. See answer number one. This won't help you. You'd also have to provide a hook for all processes.
3. The functions you describe use a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) which is a `POSIX` construct, and are user-mode simulated on other systems.

To inspect your traffic you must use a driver that will do it for you. You might want to look at [Pcap.Net](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net) which is a C# project aimed exactly at your problem, and provides the driver and API necessary.

Comment: I know pcap and other drivers like sharppcap,..., etc. but my aim is to know the process receiving or sending the captured packet which was difficult for me.  I tried to retrieve the port # from the headers(tcp&udp) and excute netstate but still not all the packets can be associated to a process, only tcp&udp.